# Received AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when use raster_geometry_mask

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio

I need to create masks (binary image) from .tif and .shp file by rasterio and geopandas. The following is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import rasterio
import rasterio.features
import rasterio.warp
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.mask import mask
import shapely
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
import geopandas as gpd

dataset = rasterio.open('/content/drive/My Drive/Data4Colab/Baitap2/img.tif')
polygons = gpd.read_file('/content/drive/My Drive/Data4Colab/Baitap2/shp/paddy_bg.shp')

shapes = []
geo = polygons.values[:, 1]
for i in range(len(polygons)):
    shapes.append(geo[i])

out = rasterio.mask.raster_geometry_mask(dataset, shapes, crop=True)
```

This is my shapes (list):

```
['background',
 'background',
 'background',
 'background',
 'background',
 'background',
 'paddy',
 'paddy',
 'paddy',
 'paddy',
 'paddy',
 'paddy']
```

And I receive an error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type mismatch issue. `rasterio.mask.raster_geometry_mask` [expects `shapes` to be *"a GeoJSON-like dict or an object that implements the Python geo interface protocol (such as a Shapely Polygon)*"](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.mask.html?highlight=raster_geometry_mask#rasterio.mask.raster_geometry_mask), but what you're reading from Geopandas probably doesn't conform to that.

One approach would be to use the [`fiona`](https://pypi.org/project/Fiona/) module to read the shapefile:

```py
import fiona
import rasterio

dataset = rasterio.open('/path/to/your/img.tif')

with fiona.open("tests/data/box.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

out = rasterio.mask.raster_geometry_mask(dataset, shapes, crop=True)
```

If you still need to do work with Geopandas after you create the masks, you can correlate them again with the Pandas DataFrame afterwards (by using simple index order or an ID property in the shapes, etc).